# Idiot's guide to installing gevent on Windows

Tags: python, visual-c++, pip, gevent

Is there an idiot's guide to installing gevent on Windows from scratch? I'm trying to install on to Windows 10 with Python 3.4. If I do a pip install then the installation blows out saying that it can't find Visual C++ compiler. (I definitely have 2017 VS Community edition installed, but obviously that's not acceptable to the installer for some reason.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has a compiler for you:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

Or you can look here:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/windows.html#compiling-python-on-windows

Or you can use MinGW

But your best bet is to install Python using anaconda.
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/compiler-tools.html

I find that conda install most modules without hassle, and is easier to manage in the long run.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to help my son learn Python but it's far too long since I did much hands-on stuff myself!

Comment: Totally understood!  Then definitely go with the conda (anaconda or the mini installer miniconda) they will make installing modules and keep the system updated far easier.  Plus I find the install to be easier then the typical python install to begin with, and they support every platform.  

Have fun!